# Muitas linhas em um arquivo csv

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, memória, lista

O cenário da minha duvida é o seguinte: Tenho um sistema que lê um arquivo que possui em torno de 3 milhões de linhas, cada linha tem um separador, eu identifico cada item na linha, faço o devido tratamento que deve ser feito em cada um desses itens, e transformo cada linha em um objeto, sendo que este objeto mais tarde é adicionando em uma lista, que é salvo depois no banco de dados. As linhas que possuem defeito devem ir para outra lista para que um arquivo com as linhas defeituosas seja gerado.

O problema acontece quando a quantidade de linhas é por exemplo 5 milhões, ocasionando estouro de memória. Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso, e como resolveu?

Answer (score 0):

Eu trabalho no PHP. Quando tenho um processamento deste tipo que 'estora' o tempo do servidor, faço uma pagina que irá consumir um serviço que será processado em background pelo servidor.

O que na maioria das vezes é dar timeout do navegador, mas o sistema continua processando.

Então utilizo dessa abordagem. Chamo um serviço que irá, por exemplo, processar o arquivo e posteriormente pode enviar um email retornando o relatório do arquivo processado ou disponibilizar o relatório em um link no sistema.